# Autohotkey; search for string in file. Pseudocode

Tags: autohotkey

I have a file like this (10 000 lines):

```
"AAHA000","name1@domain.com"  
"AAKA001","name2@domain.com"  
"AALM001","name3@domain.com"
```

What I'm trying to do is to extract the email from the second part of each line when a match is found with the 7 character username.

Here is my current pseudocode. I can't really figure out how to extract the email from the textfile. I tried to use loopread but it did not work.

```
Userid:
Gui, Submit, NoHide
{
If (strlen(tuserid) = 7)
{
Search %textfile% for tuserid
    If finds tuserid
            {
            Take the email from the same line and copy to %emailvariable%
            Guicontrol,, Email, %emailvariable%
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A file content loop and some regex will do the job. :)

```
inputFile = C:\My Data Textfile.txt
outputFile = C:\ExtractedEmails.txt
regex = ".+?","(.+?)"
Loop, read, %inputFile%, %outputFile%
{
    RegexMatch(A_LoopReadLine, regex, match)
    FileAppend, %match1%`r`n
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I misunderstood, but do you mean it can be implemented like this? I tried, but it did not work. http://p.ahkscript.org/?p=8a340b52